# How to distinguish pdf and non pdf files?

Tags: java, pdf, infinite-loop, urlconnection

I used the following snippet to download pdf files ( I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309300/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-programmatticaly-from-a-webpage-with-html-extension) , credits to [Josh M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255746/josh-m))

```
public final class FileDownloader {

    private FileDownloader(){}

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        download("http://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf", new File("sample.pdf"));
    }

    public static void download(final String url, final File destination) throws IOException {
        final URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        final FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destination, false);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int read;
        final InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        while((read = input.read(buffer)) > -1)
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

It works perfect with pdf files. However, as I encountered a "bad file" ... I do not know what the extension of that file is , but it appears that I fell into infinite loop of `while((read = input.read(buffer)) > -1)`. How can I improve this snippet to discard any kind of inappropriate files (non pdfs)?

Comment: *It works perfect with pdf files. However, as I encountered a "bad file"* -- have you checked whether this really is a question of PDF or no PDF? Have you checked the contents of the target file in such a situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a question with the similar issue: [Infinite Loop in Input Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763235/infinite-loop-in-input-stream).

Check out a possible solution: [Abort loop after fixed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870271/abort-loop-after-fixed-time).

You could try setting a timeout for the connection: [Java URLConnection Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163693/java-urlconnection-timeout).

Comment: +1 Thank you. This solution is fine for small volumes. However, it would be impractical to start a new thread for every download. I have about 37 million files to be checked